# Android/IOS Chrome is not playing audio with HTML5 audio

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, google-chrome

I am currently using HTML5 audio to play sound on particular button in my angular app, sound is coming in desktop in all browsers, but it has problem with Android/IOS browsers.

So I tried below things:

1). First I tried to play the sound through js but it is not coming as Android/IOS chrome not allow me to use audio.play(), it always give me the error, 
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() can only be initiated by a user gesture.

2). Then if it is not allowing me to use audio.play, so to avoid first i created one audio element with autoplay property in html to test that audio tag is working on mobile or not, and found that it is working.

```
<audio id = "audio1" src="s.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"  autoplay></audio>
```

So what i did that I created one html element of audio with autoplay property with javasript because i want audio to be play on click of button not on load.

```
                  var source = "s.mp3";
                  var element = document.createElement('audio');
                  element.setAttribute("src",source);
                  element.setAttribute("autoplay","");
                  document.body.appendChild(element);
```

but this is not working in mobiles chrome, looking like strange to me as I am just created the element with the same attributes as I did that in html.